# What i should use to convert specific json format

Tags: java, json, ejb

I have problem that I want to solve. I'm using `EJB3.1` to create my webservice. I'm having trouble composing a Java bean structure that will return this format in `json`

```
{
    "test": {
        "v1": "1",
        "v2": "2"
    } 
}
```

I used a Map to create it but it gave me this format:

```
{
"test": {
    "entry": [
      {
        "key": "v1",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "key": "v2",
        "value": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The class looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement    
public class TestClass {

    @XmlElement(name="test")
    private Map<String, String> map;

}
```

And this my WS method

```
@POST
@Path("new")
@Produces("application/json")
public TestClass startNew () {
    TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("v1", "1");
    map.put("v2", "2");
    testClass.setMap(map);
    return testClass;
}
```

Should I use something else instead of a map or how do I handle this format?

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier for you to use the [JSON Processing API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html) (and part of Java EE 7):

```
@POST
@Path("new")
@Produces("application/json")
public JsonObject startNew() {
    JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory(Collections.emptyMap());
    return factory.createObjectBuilder().
            add("test", factory.createObjectBuilder().
                    add("v1", 1).
                    add("v2", 2).
                    build()
            ).
            build();
}
```

Comment: can i use XmlElment instead of this way

Comment: i want to use something like map is there any way for that

Comment: JSON Processing 1.1 adds more JSON features such as patch, pointer and merge. https://readlearncode.com/java-ee/java-ee-8-json-processing-1-1-json-pointer-overview/